# @foreach loop in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Anyone see any reasons why this wouldn't work in laravel 4?  I figured I would check here before posting on github.

In the controller:

```
return View::make('home.index')
->with('bcrumbs', array("home.index" => "Home","home.privacy" =>"Privacy Policy"))
```

In the template:

```
@foreach ($bcrumbs as $k => $elem}
  <li><a href='{{ URL::route($k) }}'>{{ $elem }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Even if I remove any processing within the foreach and just write "hi", it is a total failure.  Chrome reports:

```
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

Comment: FYI - using the latest beta zip as of today.

Comment: Have you tried removing the entire @foreach loop as well to see where the problem is?

Comment: Yup - if I remove the loop, then the code executes fine.  If I just echo out the passed in variable, the data is there as expected.  I just can't loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's intentional, but you have mis-matched braces: `@foreach ($bcrumbs as $k => $elem}`: you're opening with `(` and (not) closing with `}` … maybe that's it!

Comment: I hate that I missed that.  I literally poured over this and tried every permutation I could think.. That is, beyond checking the syntax was actually valid. :)  Good eye!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the problem in question but I got an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with Laravel 4 on Ubuntu Server 12.04, the reason I'm posting this is that I ended up here so someone might find this usefull. The problem for me was the use of PHP's empty() function. Just changed this to if($your_var != null), this fixed my problem.